# Aligning the equations

Tags: equations, line-breaking

How do I align the two equations and label them?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\pd{EU}{\alpha} &= d(\theta) U'(\pi_{1}) [G_{\alpha}(\alpha, \theta, \epsilon) - \widebar{P} C_{\alpha}(\alpha, \theta)] \\     
                &+ (1-d(\theta)) U'(\pi_{0}) [G_{\alpha}(\alpha, \theta, 0) -  C_{\alpha}(\alpha, \theta)] = 0,\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\pd{EU}{\theta} &= h'(\theta)[U(\pi_{0}) - U(\pi_{1})] \\
                &+ d(\theta) U'(\pi_{1})[G_{\theta}(\alpha, \theta, \epsilon) - \widebar{P} C_{\theta}(\alpha, \theta)] \\
                &+(1-d(\theta))U'(\pi_{0})[G_{\theta}(\alpha, \theta, 0) -  1] = 0.\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Use \notag on any line you don't want an equation number.

Comment: I have changed my question

Comment: At any rate, you want to use the `{align}` environment from the `amsmath` package (included in `mathtools` as well, I think).  Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'label'? There are a couple things this could reasonably mean.